# Extract the count of keyvalue present in txt file from system date in unix or linux

Tags: linux, unix

Below file generates workcount keys value daily. I need to extract the specific count from  current date. Please help me out.

## workcount.txt

```
Sun Jul 13 01:00:01 PDT 2014
Mon Jul 14 01:00:02 PDT 2014
4d972230-0b5a-11e4-a900-0ed3c9c5b6a3
23d41150-0b74-11e4-49ac-be7a81b06437
1c4a6cc0-0b7b-11e4-258d-1ee0158edd78
85bf5e10-0b83-11e4-716f-4253342907af
8610b260-0b83-11e4-49ac-be7a81b06437
ecf70dc0-0b84-11e4-c558-b6711cc279a6
d569cca0-0b99-11e4-8d77-f2b426de171e    
Tue Jul 15 01:00:01 PDT 2014
92e85260-0c30-11e4-258d-1ee0158edd78
bdf103d0-0c30-11e4-c558-b6711cc279a6
343cf3c0-0c34-11e4-c94d-fa2a5e818fe8
34723490-0c34-11e4-c558-b6711cc279a6
3497e500-0c34-11e4-258d-1ee0158edd78
66711ad0-0c46-11e4-49ac-be7a81b06437
66dd4a20-0c46-11e4-258d-1ee0158edd78
87a28070-0c48-11e4-a900-0ed3c9c5b6a3
f19ea750-0c49-11e4-c558-b6711cc279a6
Wed Jul 16 01:00:01 PDT 2014
426ede80-0cdf-11e4-716f-4253342907af
17a1a3e0-0ce9-11e4-49ac-be7a81b06437    
1797dfe0-0ce9-11e4-c558-b6711cc279a6
176d2660-0ce9-11e4-258d-1ee0158edd78
17882870-0ce9-11e4-c94d-fa2a5e818fe8
173ca080-0ce9-11e4-dd2f-0ed3c9c5b6a3
179fcf20-0ce9-11e4-716f-4253342907af
7ebbc300-0cf6-11e4-c94d-fa2a5e818fe8
26d21980-0cfd-11e4-49ac-be7a81b06437
Thu Jul 17 01:00:01 PDT 2014
e9cf91d0-0daf-11e4-49ac-be7a81b06437
ea7d0fe0-0daf-11e4-258d-1ee0158edd78
eb50b390-0daf-11e4-716f-4253342907af
5284fa50-0dd1-11e4-dd2f-0ed3c9c5b6a3
```

Assume that **Thu Jul 17 1:05:34 PDT 2014** is current system date and I need to extract the count of the current date as shown below:

```
We had 4 connection reset work unit failures today.
```

Comment: If you are only ever dealing with today's data, then you know that there won't be another date stamp after the last one.  If you ever need to look at historical data, then you have to code to detect the start of a new date.  Given the data shown, if the first character on the line is a capital letter, it is a date line; otherwise, it is a 'connection reset work unit failure' line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v d="$(date)" 'BEGIN { c = 0; sub(/..:..:../, "..:..:..", d); d = "^" d "$" } { sub(/[ \t\r]*$/, "") } /^[A-Z][a-z][a-z] / { if (p) exit; if ($0 ~ d)p = 1; next } NF && p { ++c } END { print "We have " c " connection reset workunit failures for that day." }' your_file
```

Output:

```
We have 4 connection reset workunit failures for that day.
```

Just modify the `print` command if you really need pairs of `**` added to it.

Debug version:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    stderr = "/dev/stderr"
    counter = 0
    sub(/..:..:../, "..:..:..", date)
    date = "^" date "$"
    printf("Date pattern: %s\n", date) > stderr
}
{
    sub(/[ \t\r]*$/, "")
}
/^[A-Z][a-z][a-z] / {
    if (p) {
        printf("Found second date line: %s. Exiting.\n", $0) > stderr
        exit
    }
    if ($0 ~ date) {
        printf("Found date line: %s\n", $0) > stderr
        p = 1
    }
    next
}
NF && p {
    printf("Increasing counter for line: %s\n", $0) > stderr
    ++counter
}
END {
    print "We have " counter " connection reset workunit failures for that day."
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -v date="$(date)" -f script.awk your_file
```

Comment: I tried second also still it showing 0.Please help me. awk -v d="Thu Jul 17 01:00:01 PDT 2014" 'BEGIN { c = 0; sub(/..:..:../, "..:..:..", d); d = "^" d "$" } /^[[:alpha:]]{3}/ { if (p) exit; if ($0 ~ d) p = 1; next } NF && p { ++c } END { print "We have " c " connection reset workunit failures for that day." }' workunit4.txt
We have 0 connection reset workunit failures for that day.

Comment: @AjinkyaChavan I have to ask again, did you verify that your file is already in UNIX format? Second, is the data in the current form of your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24819203/445221) same as the actual data you have? Because with same data, it works well for me and I get an output.

Comment: @AjinkyaChavan You're probably using `mawk` or `nawk`. I made an update to make it work with it as well. Try the second version again.

Comment: -rw-r--r--. 1 sps sps 108778 Jul 19 00:42 workunit4.txt i have file in unix but i tried its showing zero. date is in correct format as in question.Again i will post the key value it does not have any * value at beginning .i.e :-  Fri Jul 18 01:00:01 PDT 2014
aa266840-0e6f-11e4-49ac-be7a81b06437
aa49cec0-0e6f-11e4-c94d-fa2a5e818fe8
b09f8300-0e6f-11e4-dd2f-0ed3c9c5b6a3

Comment: @AjinkyaChavan You can just upload it to [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/). However please take note that I made an update already. You may be using `mawk` or `nawk`.

Comment: Here i had pasted. Please look into it http://pastebin.com/P5BdknEk         And i used mawk and nawk its showning error.-bash: nawk: command not found

Comment: @AjinkyaChavan No I mean that your current /usr/bin/awk may be nawk or mawk or anything that's not GNU awk. So at least please try the second version again. Just use `awk` to run it.

Comment: @AjinkyaChavan As expected it is not in UNIX format but in DOS. Do `sed 's|\r||' key-value.txt > copy.txt` then try processing `copy.txt` instead.

Comment: no its not working.Now I change my yesterday date with current date 
Sat Jul 19 01:00:01 PDT 2014.and the ouput is showing 3 but keys are 15.

Comment: i created the file in  2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: i converted.Still its showing 3 count but count are 15,

Comment: i used this command  awk -v d="$(date)" 'BEGIN { c = 0; sub(/..:..:../, "..:..:..", d); d = "^" d "$" } /^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]/ { if (p) exit; if ($0 ~ d)p = 1; next } NF && p { ++c } END { print "We have " c " connection reset workunit failures for that day." }' w.txt

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem now. When I use the custom time `Fri Jul 18 01:00:02 PDT 2014` I get 15. Note that it's `Jul 18` not `Jul 19`. The one on the text with 15 units are from `Jul 18`. And this is the command I used: `awk -v d="Fri Jul 18 01:00:02 PDT 2014" 'BEGIN { c = 0; sub(/..:..:../, "..:..:..", d); d = "^" d "$" } /^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]/ { if (p) exit; if ($0 ~ d)p = 1; next } NF && p { ++c } END { print "We have " c " connection reset workunit failures for that day." }' temp2.txt`. It was copied from yours.

Comment: Hi Konsolebox today i am not getting right output is 19 connection error. but today keys in the file are 31.

Comment: Instead of applying `sed -i 's|\r||' file`, try `sed -ri 's|[ \t\r]+$||' file` instead.

Comment: Same output is coming i.e 19 instead of 31

Comment: can u tell me how to apply debug so i can verfiy whats going into script

Comment: @AjinkyaChavan Try the script version. I made an update.

Comment: Date pattern: ^Wed Jul 23 ..:..:.. PDT 2014$
Found date line: Wed Jul 23 01:00:01 PDT 2014
Increasing counter for line: 1373eb60-125d-11e4-258d-1ee0158edd78 goes till 19 count after that it skips and say Found second date line: ddda3a10-1269-11e4-49ac-be7a81b06437. Exiting.
We have 19 connection reset workunit failures for that day.

Comment: @AjinkyaChavan It shouldn't match `ddd` as `/^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]/` matches uppercase A to Z first. It could be a bug with your awk. Try adding a space to it: `/^[A-Z][a-z][a-z] /`

Comment: awk -v date="$(date)" -f script.awk workunit4.txt
Date pattern: ^Wed Jul 23 ..:..:.. PDT 2014$
Found date line: Wed Jul 23 01:00:01 PDT 2014
Increasing counter for line: 1373eb60-125d-11e4-258d-1ee0158edd78
Increasing counter for line: 12e91080-125d-11e4-c94d-fa2a5e818fe8
Increasing counter for line: 136e4610-125d-11e4-d919-0ed3c9c5b6a3
Increasing counter for line: 11e3d580-125d-11e4-4938-4253342907af
Increasing counter for line: b02c60a0-1266-11e4-c558-b6711cc279a6
Increasing counter for line: b6d760d0-1266-11e4-49ac-be7a81b06437

Comment: Increasing counter for line: d40f3c90-1266-11e4-258d-1ee0158edd78
Increasing counter for line: cc4d0000-1266-11e4-c94d-fa2a5e818fe8
Increasing counter for line: 0f538220-1267-11e4-4938-4253342907af
Increasing counter for line: f39a61b0-1267-11e4-c558-b6711cc279a6
Increasing counter for line: 05ce4360-1268-11e4-258d-1ee0158edd78
Increasing counter for line: 093c19f0-1268-11e4-49ac-be7a81b06437
Increasing counter for line: f3cf0640-1267-11e4-c94d-fa2a5e818fe8
Increasing counter for line: f44a02a0-1267-11e4-c94d-fa2a5e818fe8

Comment: Increasing counter for line: 40354850-1268-11e4-d919-0ed3c9c5b6a3
Increasing counter for line: 4039b520-1268-11e4-c94d-fa2a5e818fe8
Increasing counter for line: 493275e0-1268-11e4-c558-b6711cc279a6
Increasing counter for line: f0cd10e0-1267-11e4-c94d-fa2a5e818fe8
Increasing counter for line: 3fde27a0-1268-11e4-4938-4253342907af
Found second date line: ddda3a10-1269-11e4-49ac-be7a81b06437. Exiting.
We have 19 connection reset workunit failures for that day.

Comment: i had attached the output in above comment  please verify it.

Comment: ya thank you got right output now. We have 31 connection reset workunit failures for that day.

Comment: Ok. The new script may not require converting your file to UNIX format as well as it already trims out trailing spaces including `\r` on every line.

Comment: Which debug script ?can i add \r  into awk -v d="$(date)" 'BEGIN { c = 0; sub(/..:..:../, "..:..:..", d); d = "^" d "$" } /^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]/ { if (p) exit; if ($0 ~ d)p = 1; next } NF && p { ++c } END { print "We have " c " connection reset workunit failures for that day." }' your_file this script

Comment: I have updated both. What I mean is you don't need to do `sed` anymore.`

Comment: Hi Konsolebox i need your help on this question please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647462/i-need-to-send-mail-if-the-count-stuck-in-pending-status-more-than-5-min-in-unix –  Ajinkya Chavan

Answer (score 0):

If this format is unique then you can use following:-

```
i=0;
grep ":" |while a
do
    time[$i]=$a;
    i=`expr $i+1`
done
```

later you can check array for duplicate values then calculate them and `echo` that according to you.

Comment: Hi Konsolebox i need your help on this question please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647462/i-need-to-send-mail-if-the-count-stuck-in-pending-status-more-than-5-min-in-unix